# Finding the shortest closed path

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

We are given the following 7 points P1, P2, …, P7 in the plane whose x and y co-ordinates are as follows:

Point             P1    P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  P7

x-value               10    12  19  11  12  14  18

y-value               25    23  17  6   20  23  25

We wish to find the shortest closed tour that connects all the 7 points under the restriction that the tour starts at the left-most point and goes strictly rightward to the rightmost point, and then go strictly leftward back to the starting point.
Can anyone suggest a dynamic approach(algorithm) to this problem?

Comment: You have to put some effort in solving the problem to get help..

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use brute force? There are only 7! = 5040 possible tours. 6! = 720 if you always start with the leftmost point.

Comment: Some basic research would have been nice. After entering "shortest closed path" into google, clicking the first (wikipedia) link, and then ["related problems"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Related_problems), I'm one click away from getting the correct page.

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the Travelling Salesman Problem.

Comment: There are 2^5 possible paths from left to right and similarly from right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated, there are 2^5 (32) possible paths from left to right and right to left. Just evaluate each of these and choose the shortest.

You can choose each middle point either while going left or going right. Hence 2^5 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple
squareroot((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)
x2 is the x of p2 and x1 is the point of p1 then taking all the distance and get the smallest result

or you can also see the dijekstra algorithm as well